# How do python handles "self" attribute of a class internally, when the method is assigned to a variable

Tags: python, class

Recently, I was looking into the "getattr" method, and one interesting behaviour is that it could return a method of a class instance and assign it to a variable. Here's the example I played with:

```py
class Example:
    def some_method(self, param1):
        print(param1)

example = Example()
method1 = getattr(example, "some_method")
print(method1)
method1("hi")
```

And here's the output:

```
<bound method Example.some_method of <__main__.Example object at 0x7f82cbcb2850>>
hi
```

I do understand for the first line of the output that the **method1** is a "bound method" type related to the actual instance **example**. But for the function call involving the method `method1("hi")`, the "self" parameter is omitted, only the "param1" value is given. I wonder how this function call is processed successfully and where the "self" parameter is actually stored internally.

Comment: The same way `example.some_method('hi')` works

Comment: There are many questions about `self`, for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/2709821/407651. The quality of the answers varies, but are you really asking a question that hasn't been asked and answered already?

Answer (score 0):

Methods rely on the mechanism called [descriptors](https://realpython.com/python-descriptors/). Any type can be made a descriptor by implementing methods such as `__get__`. For example:

```
class D:
    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        return f'Some value from {obj.__class__.__name__}'

class A:
    d = D()

print(A().d)  # 'Some value from A'
```

Python attribute access mechanism will recognize the descriptor and delegate the access logic to its `__get__()`, `__set__()`, etc. Now, the plot twist is that Python functions also implement the descriptor protocol, that defines how they behave when accessed as methods. For example, if we have a method `A.f()`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
       self.x = x

    def f(self, y):
        return self.x + y
```

then this code:

```
a = A(2)
print(a.f(3))  # prints 5
```

in fact runs as:

```
a = A(2)
bound_f = A.__get__(a)
print(bound_f(3))   # also prints 5
```

So when a function is accessed as a non-static method, it intercepts the access via te descriptor protocol and returns a bound method object, with attribute `__self__` set to the object on which it was accessed:

```
>>> print(bound_f)
<bound method A.f of <__main__.A object at 0x7fc13db99ac0>>
>>> print(bound_f.__self__)
<__main__.A at 0x7fc13db99ac0>
```

Static, class methods and properties are also implemented using descriptors.